# How do I effectively submit a system level concept for Ubuntu tablet for consideration?

Tags: application-development

The concept is akin to the implementation of swiftkey in BB10 operating system.  It would have to interface with all applications so, while it could gain traction as a standalone application, it would be best if the operating system were designed to accommodate the idea.

I'm not asking for anyone to review the proposal here.  I just want to find the right channel so that someone in the right position takes the required 10 minutes to read the proposal and the required 10 minutes to imagine the possibilities.

If it's trash then tell me no thank you.  But if it is a good idea, that person would be in a position to advocate for the concept within the organization.

Answer (score 3):

Post your proposal at the [Ubuntu-devel-discuss](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-devel-discuss) mailing list

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the link to accomplish this task.  I will polish and submit with illustrations.